# Grails Quartz Plugin - No signature of triggerNow()

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-4

I'm trying to trigger a job manually from a controller in my Grails4 application.

I'm seeing this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.myapp.MyJob.triggerNow() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[foo:It works]]
```

I've seen older posts with the same issue, but they were using older versions of the plugin and I have tried all of the suggestions (package of controller and job the same, inject the quartzScheduler in the controller).

Here's my controller:

```
package com.myapp

class MyController {
    def quartzScheduler

    def myAction() {
        MyJob.triggerNow([foo:"It works"])
    }
}
```

Here's my job:

```
package com.myapp

class MyJob {
    static triggers = {}

    def execute(context) {
        println context.mergedJobDataMap.get('foo')
    }
}
```

My build.gradle file has this:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'                        
compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1'
```

Comment: In which folder did you put the MyJob class?

Comment: @luisenricke The MyJob class is in grails-app/jobs/com/myapp